# Weird problem with preg_replace and chinese character

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding

i have this werid problem. After a preg_replace, some chinese character became funky character. this is the script.

```
$message = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']),'<img><vid>');
echo $message;
$message = removewhitespace($message);
echo $message;

function removewhitespace($a)
{
return preg_replace('/(\\\r\\\n\\\r\\\n)+/','\r\n\r\n', preg_replace('/^(\\\r\\\n)+|(\\\r\\\n)+$/', '', preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', preg_replace('/^\s+|\s+$/', '', $a))));
}
```

The display would be

```
好不好你
好不好�
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `'u'` modifier to your patterns (e.g. `'/(\\\r\\\n\\\r\\\n)+/u'` instead of `'/(\\\r\\\n\\\r\\\n)+/'`) and make sure the subject is in UTF-8.

Only this way will your input be interpreted as UTF-8 instead of a single-byte encoding.

Comment: Still relative and valid, that u on the end solves it!

Answer (score 2):

Use `\p{Z}` instead of `\s` in your regex

Answer (score 0):

Unicode characters take up multiple bytes whereas ASCII characters take up one. You probably need to do a multibyte search `mb_ereg_replace` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php