# preg_replace error with regex with non-english characters, character is not recognized

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding, preg-replace, special-characters

I am using the following function to remove white-spaces from strings:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);
```

I am inputting this string of french characters: `ù û ü ÿ à â æ ç é è ê ë ï î ô` notice each has a space in-between.

The `à` character isn't recognized; this is how the output looks: `ùûüÿ�âæçéèêëïîô`

Any idea why? I have tried converting the str to UTF-8 before hand as well to no avail.

---

Update: I found the following post ([Weird problem with preg_replace and chinese character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148216/weird-problem-with-preg-replace-and-chinese-character)) where adding `u` to the end of the regex corrects the problem like so:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $str);
```

This seems to fix it, but could someone explain why this is happening along with an official solution explaining what the `u` is doing in this regex?

Comment: Is your page in UTF8? Works here, https://eval.in/447334 ...is the sample string your exact string?

Comment: The `u` is a unicode modifier, http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php. It works without it though... or at least works here and on `eval`..

Comment: Yes it is the exact string. The character is messed up sent through email as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the PHP regex engine considers your string as a suit of bytes (i.e. as a suit of one byte characters).

When you use the u modifier, the regex engine changes two things:

- Strings are seen as utf8 strings (so characters are encoded with eventually multiple bytes)
- the meaning of shorthand character classes (like `\s`, `\w`, `\d`...) changes to include unicode characters instead of only ascii characters.

Note that these two changes can be written explicitly like this too, at the start of the pattern instead of using the u modifier:

```
(*UTF8)(*UCP)yourpattern
```

You can find the complete documentation of the pcre regex engine used by PHP [here](http://pcre.org/original/pcre.txt).

Comment: This. In case you'd like to go deeper and see an excerpt from the PCRE docs about `PCRE_UTF8` and `PCRE_UCP`, see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30113100/3764814).

Comment: Any idea why the code outputs correctly here: https://eval.in/447341 yet when I run it on my computer it outputs incorrectly? I am running PHP on IIS 7.5, PHP 5.6.0, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @user2704343: It is possible that the libpcre used by eval.in was compiled to use UTF mode by default.

Comment: Did you specify your output encoding properly (Try `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`)?

Comment: @user2704343: Yes, try to add `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` if you display your result in a browser (or check the source).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski and @CasimiretHippolyte I tried both `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` and `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` it changed nothing. (Just noticed I had some random user name... :P)

Comment: Well... ironically string handling is one thing PHP gets terribly wrong. Try to build an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it as a different question.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski thanks for the help on this :) I think the above answer does explain the differences in the characters regarding how PHP handles them, which is useful. My problem must be related to the specific development environment I have set up.